# Find value of $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} a^k \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{a^k}\right)^k (1-\frac{1}{a^k})^{n-k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We need to find value of such series :

$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} a^k \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{a^k}\right)^k (1-\frac{1}{a^k})^{n-k}$, where $a > 1$.

Maybe it's possible to represent it using a moment of binomial distribution?

Comment: At the very least, have you already tried combining all the powers of $k$ together?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician I've make a misstake , edited

Comment: My question still stands. Here is another one: do you recall what the binomial theorem looks like?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician you mean about : $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k \le n} \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n - k}$? Anyway , I've combine all powers and get : $\sum \binom{n}{k} (1 - \frac{1}{a^k})^n (\frac{a^k - 1}{a})^k$

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician sorry , maybe I missunderstand something, but that's not looks so easy. Actiually it looks like finding generating function of binomial distribution.

Comment: @Thorgott but $k$ is not a fixed constant.

Comment: Would it help you if I rewrite your expression as $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{a}{a^k}\right)^k\left(1-\frac1{a^k}\right)^{n-k}$$?

Comment: The  Multinomial theorem !!! may be !!!!

Comment: @logo it look's loke so , but I don't see the main parts of Multinomial theorem